# Issues with tester results

Tags: java

My assignment:

The game of Stix – similar to a game played on "Survivor, Thailand" some time ago – in a simplified version somehow looks like this:

It is played by two players (in Survivor it were more than two, but here we just deal with two). A number of sticks (like matches) are placed on a table. The first player takes 1, 2 or 3 sticks away, provided that there that many on the table. Then the second player takes 1, 2 or 3 sticks away (if possible), and so on. Whoever takes the last stick, loses.

This is my class:

```
public class StixBoard
{
  public int number;

  public StixBoard(int number)
  {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public int getNumStix()
  {
    return number;
  }

  public boolean takeStix(int number)
  {
    int take = 0;

    while(take != number && number <= 3 && number > 0)
    {
      number = this.number - take;
      take++;
    }

    if(this.number >= 1 && this.number <= 3)
    {
      number = number - this.number;
      System.out.println("Number of sticks on board:" + number);
      return(true);
    }
    else
      System.out.println("Illegeal Move");
    return(false);
  }

  public boolean isGameOver()
  {
    if(number >=1)
    {
      return(true);
    }
    else
      return false;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return(getNumStix() + " Stix Remaining.");
  }
}
```

This is my tester:

```
public class StixGame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    StixBoard game1 = new StixBoard(6);
    System.out.println(game1.getNumStix());
    System.out.println(game1.takeStix(1));
    System.out.println(game1.getNumStix());
    }

}
```

I cant seem to shy away from this output:

```
6
Illegeal Move
false
6
```

Comment: I see shadowing of variables in your code

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the variable `number` way too many times, this will make your code extremely confusing... Using an IDE to rename the variable in your class to `totalStix`, the problems become instantly obvious.

- Your `takeStix` method shouldn't need a while loop. All that's happening is one player is taking stix away, right? So remove that code.
- Then, it becomes clear (now that the variable naming is less confusing) that you're treating the number of remaining sticks as the number to be taken away, so switch all those variables.
- Also, rename the argument of the method to `take`, because that's what you're taking away.

You're left with the following code (with a few other minor tweaks):

```
public class StixBoard
{
  public int totalStix;

  public StixBoard(int number)
  {
    this.totalStix = number;
  }

  public int getNumStix()
  {
    return totalStix;
  }

  public boolean takeStix(int take)
  {
    if(take >= 1 && take <= 3)
    {
      totalStix -= take;
      System.out.println("Number of sticks on board:" + totalStix);
      return true;
    }

    System.out.println("Illegeal Move");
    return false ;
  }

  public boolean isGameOver()
  {
    if(totalStix >=1)
    {
      return(true);
    }
    else
      return false;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
    return(getNumStix() + " Stix Remaining.");
  }
}
```